# Can $18$ consecutive integers be separated into two groups,such that their product is equal?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

*Can* $18$ *consecutive positive integers be separated into two groups, such that their product is equal?  We cannot leave out any number and neither we can take any number more than once.*

My work:
When the smallest number is not  $17$ or its multiple, there cannot exist any such arrangement as $17$ is a prime.

When the smallest number is a multiple of $17$ but not of $13$ or $11$, then no such arrangement exists.

But what happens, when the smallest number is a multiple of $ 17 $ and $13$ or $11$ or both?
Please help!

Comment: Are we restricted to positive integers?

Comment: @abiessu.yes actually.

Comment: @abiessu: In fact it's irrelevant. If all integers are negative, it's the same problem; and if some are positive and some negative, then one of them must be zero, which makes the thing trivially impossible.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

This is impossible.

At most one of the integers can be divisible by $19$. If there is such an integer, then one group will contain it and the other one will not. The first product is then divisible by $19$ whereas the second is not (since $19$ is prime) --- a contradiction.

So if this possible, the remainders of the numbers after division by $19$ must be precisely $1,2,3,\cdots,18$.

Now let $x$ be the product of the numbers in one of the groups. Then

$x^2 \equiv 18! \equiv -1 \pmod{19}$

by [Wilson's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem). However $-1$ is not a quadratic residue mod $19$, because the only possible squares mod $19$ are $1,4,9,16,6,17,11,7,5$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate the solution after the contradiction?

Comment: @Hawk After the contradiction he checks the case when neither of the numbers is divisible by 19. So if $x$ is the product of all numbers in one group, then $x^2$ is the product of all numbers, becuase note that both groups have the same product(We assumed that). But also we know that the product of all numbers is $18!$

Comment: @Stefan4024.is $18!$ or divisible by $18!$?

Comment: @Hawk The product of all the numbers, and $18!$, leave the same remainder after division by $19$: they are congruent modulo $19$.

Comment: @Stefan4024.Did you mean product of the remainders is $18!$?

Comment: @KonstantinArdakov. Ok.Very nice solution! Thanks!

Comment: @Hawk You're welcome.

Comment: Can this be generalized to any number of consecutive integers?

Comment: @Brilliand No idea if it's true in general, but this method of proof works exactly as well (and the argument is identical) for $p-1$ consecutive integers, where $p \equiv 3 \mod 4$ is a prime. If $p$ is not prime, the argument fails at Wilson's theorem; if $p$ is $1\mod 4$, then the argument fails at quadratic residues ($-1$ is a residue for $p \equiv 1$)

Comment: @Brilliand Yes, it's true for any number of consecutive integers. See the other answer.

Comment: Beautiful solution! I especially love the appearance of Wilson's theorem.

Comment: Fantastic proof.

Answer (score 51):

If $18$ consecutive positive integers could be separated into two groups with equal products, then the product of all $18$ integers would be a perfect square. However, the product of two or more consecutive positive integers can never be a perfect square, according to a famous theorem of P. Erdős, [Note on products of consecutive integers](http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1939-03.pdf), J. London Math. Soc. 14 (1939), 194-198.

Comment: In the same way, can we say the product of 4 consecutive numbers cannot be separated in two groups such that their product is equal? Because 5 is prime, only one member will be divisible by 5.

Comment: Although note that Erdős doesn't actually prove it for products of fewer than 100 consecutive numbers: he just refers to a paper by Seimatsu Narumi, *Tôhoku Math. Journal*, 11 (1917), 128-142 which apparently proves cases up to 202 consecutive numbers by special arguments.

Comment: @Fabinout Maybe none of them is divisible by $5$. Anyway, the Erdős-Narumi theorem applies to any number (greater than $1$ of course) of consecutive numbers. The case of $4$ consecutive numbers is trivial, just observe that $(n^2+3n)^2\lt n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)\lt(n^2+3n+1)^2$.

Comment: @RosieF In my comment I was not referring to the $n=4$ case of the assertion that $n$ consecutive numbers can't be separated into two groups with equal products (as in the original question), but rather to the $n=4$ case of the stronger assertion that the product of $n$ consecutive numbers can't be a perfect square.