# Can the product of $k$ conseuctive integers be a perfect square?

Tags: number-theory

Let $k\ge 2$ be an integer. Can a product of $k$ consecutive integers be a perfect square?

Comment: @THELONEWOLF.: any as long as finite.

Comment: Let $k>0$ be an integer, can product of $k$ consecutive integer be a perfect square?

Comment: @THELONEWOLF.: You have vandalised this question! Changing "can" to "Can" is perhaps laudable, but surely unnecessary. Changing "doesn't" to "does not" is officious and annoying. Changing "perfect" to "peqrfect" is beyond comprehension.

Comment: @123: You should edit that change into your question, rather than leaving it in a comment.

Comment: @123 why not prime numbers??

Comment: Trivially, it works for $k = 1$ with the one integer being a square number.

Comment: Any good theorem should have a proof without using primes, we have to learn to live without primes.
—123

Comment: I have got something with prime, but since you do not want a proof with prime numbers then it is okay.

Comment: @6005 but i want a proof that does not using primes.

Comment: By the way, This is good question. +1

Comment: Possibly inspirational: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/638646

Comment: See also [product of six consecutive integers being a perfect square](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90894) for references and an idea of the difficulty of this question.

Comment: Something tells me you won't be successful if it required heavy use of prime numbers to proof this by one of the brightest mathematician of 20th century, but well what do I know...

Comment: @Sil, I am still thinking what problem OP has got with prime numbers, they are beautiful.

Comment: @THELONEWOLF. Yea, using primes is nothing bad, I would say quite opposite. Primes are building blocks in number theory, seems quite unnatural to avoid them. I would understand avoiding using advanced theorems, but primes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is [HERE $1$](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ijm/1256050816), and [HERE $2$](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=10&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjRsq-Pgu3QAhVDs48KHc9RBtcQFghXMAk&url=http%3A%2F%2Folympiads.mccme.ru%2Flktg%2F2008%2F1%2F1-1en.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGRLvP5fd2-Hy5gGO-SYiom44mnag&sig2=UqYu8SX_OKdykaWV4STUSg). I think copying/describing this text will take an entire hour which is not good for my fingers. So, just look at the paper I have given.

Note that the theorem in the paper $1$ is a generalised one. **It states that The product of two or more consecutive positive integers is never a power.** And your squares also come under this section.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your helpful comments. I have already read the article that you've linked, it is using primes. I want a proof that doesn't using primes, but thank you for your answer.

Comment: Thanks @123. I have linked another paper.

Comment: @123 Why don't you accept primes in the proof? This is almost as saying "I  want a proof that doesn't use integers, but thank you for your efforts".

Comment: I would agree with you @Dietrich Burde in this case. I m trying to convince OP in this matter for hours but no result.

Comment: The article that you've linked after the first one is helped me. This answer is    what I'm looking for!

Comment: Pleasure @123...